# React Vite.config.ts dynamic data for build assetsDir

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a React App that uses Vite.
Everything is working as expected but I would like to see if we can customize the vite configuration further.

My goal is to make sure that my React app can be deployed from different subdirectories if needed and to make sure that we can serve the assets from different locations.

With my current set-up, my Vite config has the following:

vite.config.ts

```
  build: {
      // Tells the app where the assets will be served from.
      assetsDir: "./apps/my-react-app",
      sourcemap: false,
    }
```

Everything is working as expected as long as I keep the production bundle files within  "/apps/my-react-app" in production.

Is it possible for the vite.config.ts file to read a variable from, lets say the global window object?
This will enable me to declare something like  window.assetsServedFrom = "./apps/another_directory_for_build_files" and then my vite config will be:

vite.config.ts

```
  build: {
      // Tells the app where the assets will be served from.
      assetsDir: window.assetsServedFrom,
      sourcemap: false,
    }
```

I tried different ways to read a window variable but haven't been successful.

It would be really great if this is possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The vite config file is a static module which means that it not executed within the context of the browser and so, cannot access the `window` object. An alternative way to achieve what you want is to use environment variables.

You need to create a `.env` file in your project root and declare your variable there. For example

```
VITE_ASSETS_SERVED_FROM=./apps/my-react-app
```

And then in your vite config file, you can access the variable by using `import.meta.env`. Here's an example;

```
build: {
  assetsDir: import.meta.env.VITE_ASSETS_SERVED_FROM,
  sourcemap: false
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was actually able to implement this as well.  However, I need the `.env` variable to be dynamic.  Is there a way for the `.env` variable to read a window global variable and use that as its own value?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the [`base` path](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) to `./`

With this setting your project will be built with relative references to your assets, instead of absolute paths.

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  build: {
    assetsDir: './apps/my-react-app',
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

For example, here is example `index.html` when built with default `base: '/'` (absolute paths from root)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/apps/my-react-app/index-afa5457f.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/my-react-app/index-d526a0c5.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the same `index.html` with `base: './'` (relative paths):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./apps/my-react-app/index-57f96858.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./apps/my-react-app/index-d526a0c5.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this change could deploy your built site to any public path and the project should load correctly (as long as you maintain the relative locations of the built assets to one another).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input.  It seems that from the example vite config you shared, the assets dir still needs to be declared.  I was looking for a way where the app can be deployed in any subdirectory and at the same time, have the app consume a variable that will tell it where the assets will be coming from.  This is possible with webpack and so I was hoping I can achieve the same effect with vite.